# csv to yaml with multiple testing

Tags: python, csv, yaml

I am trying to write a python function that can change the csv to yaml
Now my csv is looking like

```
name,description,tests
product_id,ID of the product,not null|unique
product_name,Name of the product,not null
```

I want the output to be

```
 - name : product_id
   description: ID of the product
   tests:
   - not null
   - unique
 - name: product_name
   description: Name of the product
   tests: 
   - not null
```

now I only have this

```
for row_index, row in enumerate(datareader):
  if row_index == 0:
    # let's do this once here
    data_headings = list()
    for heading_index, heading in enumerate(row):
      fixed_heading = heading.lower().replace(" ", "_").replace("-", "")
      data_headings.append(fixed_heading)
      if fixed_heading == "type":
        type_index = heading_index
      elif fixed_heading == "childfields":
        child_fields_index = heading_index
  else:
    content = dict()
    is_array = False
    for cell_index, cell in enumerate(row):

     content[data_headings[cell_index]] = cell
     is_array = (cell_index == type_index) and (cell == "array")
    result.append(content)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's standard library has a module that handles CSV files. It's `DictReader` class
assumes the first line of the input file to be the column names (unless you provide the fieldnames argument).
Using that you only need to do something special for the field name 'tests'. Unfortunately
it cannot (yet) handle `pathlib.Path()` instances, so you have to open the file yourself.

The resulting data structure you should dump with `ruamel.yaml`, which you have to install in your virtualenv e.g. with `python -m pip install ruamel.yaml`. It is a YAML 1.2 (disclaimer: I am the author of that package).

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

input = Path('input.csv')
output = Path('output.yaml')

data = []
reader = csv.DictReader(input.open(newline=''))
for row in reader:
    d = {}
    data.append(d)
    for field in reader.fieldnames:
        d[field] = row[field].split('|') if field == 'tests' else row[field]

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, output)

print(output.read_text())
```

which gives:

```
- name: product_id
  description: ID of the product
  tests:
  - not null
  - unique
- name: product_name
  description: Name of the product
  tests:
  - not null
```

Answer (score 0):

A more pythonic solution in my opinion:

```
import yaml
import csv

with open('sample_data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        item = {}
        item['name'] = row['name']
        item['description'] = row['description']
        item['tests'] = row['tests'].split('|')
        data.append(item)

with open('output.yaml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f)
```

Input:

```
name,description,tests
product_id,ID of the product,not null|unique
product_name,Name of the product,not null
```

Output:

```
- description: ID of the product
  name: product_id
  tests:
  - not null
  - unique
- description: Name of the product
  name: product_name
  tests:
  - not null
```